# Creating a table grouping and Ordering elements based in criteria

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-wrangling

I have the following dataset:

| PRODUCT | REGION | REP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| REG-YH-67 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-68 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-77 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-30 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-14 | WEST | ALEX |
| REG-YH-33 | WEST | ALEX |
| REG-YH-16 | WEST | WILL |
| REG-YH-16 | WEST | WILL |
| REG-YH-53 | WEST | WILL |
| REG-YH-13 | OUT-OF-REG | WILL |
| REG-YH-42 | OUT-OF-REG | MARTHA |
| REG-YH-67 | OUT-OF-REG | MARTHA |
| REG-YH-68 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-77 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-30 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-68 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-77 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-30 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE |
| REG-YH-13 | OUT-OF-REG | JANE |
| REG-YH-42 | OUT-OF-REG | JANE |

I want to be able to GROUP by REGION and COUNT how many times a  product was sold, but I want to be able to create a table that will show me the best top3 selling products by region, I know that first I have to group by REGION and COUNT but I want my final output to look like this:

| REGION | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NORTH | REG-YH-9 | REG-YH-77 | REG-YH-30 |
| OUT-OF-REG | REG-YH-13 | REG-YH-42 | REG-YH-67 |
| WEST | REG-YH-16 | REG-YH-14 | REG-YH-53 |

because these are the TOP 3 products by region and I want to be able to see the best selling product (COLUMN ONE) and the the REGION in the left-handside of the table, and also I want this table to be able to recalculate itself if I have a filter in the page that will filter the REP (sales representative) so that my table will update filtering REP---.

I have found Power PI isn't like Python or R. I am looking for DAX or code answers.

Comment: How do you rank products with the equal count? or you want all? like `REG-YH-42; REG-YH-9` ? Do you want to know if Jane has top, or you want to know what is top for Jane?

Comment: Hello Thank you mike for your time, I would like to know how my final table would look like once I filter my whole pbi page by REP, not if Jane is on the top, thank you so much I will be very thankful if you could help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of tied rankings in your data, but seem to return them at random for your results.

The Power Query code below does the same.

To enter this code, from the Home tab select Transform data, then from the Power Query home tab, select Advanced Editor and paste the code below into the window that opens.

You will need to change the first statement to reflect your actual data source.

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table21"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PRODUCT", type text}, {"REGION", type text}, {"REP", type text}}),

//Group by REGION
//For each Region, Group again by Product and aggregate by count
//   Then sort each table by the count
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"REGION"}, {
        {"PRODUCT", each Table.Sort(Table.Group(_,"PRODUCT",{
            {"COUNT", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}
                }), {"COUNT", Order.Descending})}
    }),

//extract the top 3 into separate columns
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "1", each [PRODUCT][PRODUCT]{0}, type text),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "2", each [PRODUCT][PRODUCT]{1}, type text),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "3", each [PRODUCT][PRODUCT]{1}, type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"PRODUCT"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Results** from your data*
[image]

Comment: Ron this is beyond amazing I didnt know  that Power Query code was used in power bi I though DAX was the only way thank you so much for taking your tome and sharing your knolowgde with me from the bottom of my heart thank you, I have a final question lets just say I want the top 10.. It will be only a matter of replicating the last lines of your code with the proper index? right?

Comment: @R_Student That would be one way to do it. Depending on your data, you might need to add a test to ensure that there are at least ten items to be returned.  That can be done using `try...otherwise` to catch the error.  And there are other ways of  handling this also.

Comment: Hey Ron hello! I hope you are doing great! I have a question, by the way your code worked 10/10 but when I try to use a global filter that I have on my PBI page the table does not re-calculate or changes values-- is there a way to change your great code to allow the previous to happen? I mean that all we can have by REGION the top 3 best selling products but also filter by REP so if I chose REP==JANE my table will show the top 3 selling prducts of JANE? thank you so much you are the best

Comment: @R_Student I don't believe that to be possible. After all, there is no REP data in the information being returned to PBI.  Either your filters would need to change a parameter in the query, or you'd need to develop a DAX solution in PBI.

Comment: Thank you Ron! I appreciate your knowledge I will look for a fix using DAX! I will be following your post to learn more from you take care